# How to read custom property attributes in C# TDO

Tags: c#, attributes

In my class I have these properties with custom attributes:

```
internal class Lands
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    [Searchable]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Searchable]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Searchable]
    public List<string> Keywords { get; set; }
    [Searchable]
    public string PublicRecordId { get; set; }
}
```

I need to send the names of ["Name", "Description", "Keywords", "PublicRecordId"] to the search engine.

Is there a way that I can get at "Lands" and retrieve a List of the property names programmatically? Right now I keep a separate list of these values but it is a pain to keep that list up to date with changes to the data structure.

Comment: `Searchable` is a self-made attribute?

Comment: You can get the propery names with [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt656691.aspx): `typeof(Lands).GetProperties()`